# auto dropdown hides behind the footer div?

Tags: html, css

i have a in auto complete input field when i type some alphabet in it the drop down opens automatically. but that hides behind the footer div.
i also check it with z-index but still the problem remains the same.
Any hint ???
****CSS for dropdow div is ****

```
div.suggestionsBox {
background-color: #F1F1F1;
border: 1px solid #D8DCE3;
float: left;
font-size: 10px;
max-height: 400px;
overflow-y: scroll;
position: absolute;
width: 320px;
z-index: 99;
```

}

Comment: Is your footer CSS property `position: fixed`?

Comment: The info is insufficient, a sample page/fiddle would help.

Comment: @farmerjoe footer has not position

Answer (score 2):

give z-index to footer div as lower value than dropdown box div

```
div.suggestionsBox 
      {
          z-index:99;
      }
.footer
      {
         z-index:2;
      }
```

Comment: i already check this even i gave z-index in minus but it is still there?

Comment: footer has no position as well only the dropdown div have position

Comment: kindly give your full code or give the jsfiddle then only i ll help u

Comment: i tell you all the scenario

Comment: sorry mehar without jsfiddle i cant or just give footer div css